# jQuery UI date picker does not add button to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following function which I call on dynamically created `input` elements of type `date` after wrapping them in `$(...)`.

```
function addDatePicker(jQueryObject) {
  jQueryObject.datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: urlToImage,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    yearRange: "c-10:c+10",
    showButtonPanel: true
  });
}
```

I can see, when inspecting the page elements in Chrome, that the class `hasDatePicker` is correctly added to the `input` tag. However, the `img` tag containing the button is **not** added.

What am I doing wrong? The `input` tag is inside a `td` tag. Might that be the reason?

Comment: what are you passing as jQueryObject?

Comment: @josh: `$(element)` where `element` is the dynamically created `HTMLInputElement` corresponding to the `<input>` tag.

Comment: do you get any console errors?

Comment: No, nothing. I can step through the internals of jQuery UI and it seems to create the appropriate `<img>` element. But I can't see where it is supposed to be added to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your image URL
or use img url (http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif)

Check working code on http://jsfiddle.net/cvPCL/

```
buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
```

Comment: Thanks, that made me realise that I'm a bit of an idiot. I called `addDatePicker` before attaching the `HTMLInputElement` to the page. Of course jQuery UI cannot add an `img` tag to a non-existing parent element!

Comment: The cal image is not working anymore... pointing to another cal picture so the example is visible
http://jsfiddle.net/24FGc/1/